# Is there a Minecraft Java client mod for managing inventory from another device?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The idea is that I could use a phone or tablet to connect to my local Minecraft instance (perhaps it's running a local server) and have an inventory screen available, and I could use the device to move around my inventory, change my hotbar, perhaps drop items and do 2x2 crafting as well. You could think of it like using a detached version of the touch screen on the Nintendo 3DS.

Does a mod like this exist? If not, is there a reason it could not exist (e.g. because certain forms of communication are blocked even under Minecraft mods), or could it theoretically be made?

(EDIT: To clarify, I tried searching for a mod like this online, but Minecraft inventory is a very loaded search topic, and the results I'm getting are all about changing the way Minecraft's inventory UI behaves in game, or changing the properties of the inventory from a gameplay perspective.)

Comment: I am sorry, but you will not find the answers you are looking for here. We're not a site where we recommend games, servers, hardware, or software.